# Firestore Query Not Filtering Data by Date in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, datetime, google-cloud-firestore, filter

I'm building a Flutter application where I'm fetching data from Firestore and trying to filter it based on a date range. However, despite implementing the filtering logic, I'm not getting any data when applying the date range filter.

Here's an overview of my implementation:

I have a Firestore collection named 'transactions' where each document has a 'date' field representing the transaction date in the format 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.Milliseconds'.
In my Flutter app, I'm using a StreamBuilder to fetch data from Firestore and applying filters based on user selections.
The date range filter is implemented using the where method on the Firestore query, where I'm checking if the 'date' field is greater than or equal to the selected 'fromDate' and less than or equal to the selected 'toDate'.
I've verified that the selected date range is correctly set and the Firestore query is constructed with the appropriate filters.
However, despite all this, I'm not getting any data when applying the date range filter. Other filters such as transaction type and trading status are working fine.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
    import 'package:estock_test/controller/filtering_controller.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class FilteringScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FilteringScreenState createState() => _FilteringScreenState();
}

class _FilteringScreenState extends State<FilteringScreen> {
  final FilteringController filteringController =
      Get.put(FilteringController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Filtering Screen'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.filter_alt),
            onPressed: () async {
              await _showFilterDialog(context);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: _buildStreamBuilder(),
    );
  }

  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot> _buildStreamBuilder() {
    CollectionReference transactions =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('transaction');

    // Build query based on selected filters
    Query filteredQuery = transactions;

    if (filteringController.selectedTransactionType.isNotEmpty) {
      filteredQuery = filteredQuery.where('transactionType',
          isEqualTo: filteringController.selectedTransactionType);
    }

    if (filteringController.selectedTrading != null) {
      filteredQuery = filteredQuery.where('trading',
          isEqualTo: filteringController.selectedTrading);
    }

    if (filteringController.selectedFromDate != null &&
        filteringController.selectedToDate != null) {
      // Filter by date range
      try {
        filteredQuery = filteredQuery.where(
          'date',
          isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: filteringController.selectedFromDate!,
          isLessThanOrEqualTo: filteringController.selectedToDate!.add(
            Duration(days: 1),
          ),
        );

        print(filteredQuery.toString());
        print(
            '  Date Range: ${filteringController.selectedFromDate} - ${filteringController.selectedToDate}');
      } catch (error) {
        print('Error applying date filter: $error');
      }
    }

    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: filteredQuery.snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          print(snapshot.error);
          return Center(child: Text('ERROR: ${snapshot.error}'));
        }
        if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data == null) {
          return Center(child: Text('No data.'));
        }

        var docs = snapshot.data!.docs;
        if (docs.isEmpty) {
          return Center(child: Text('No filtered data.'));
        }

        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: docs.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            var data = docs[index];
            // Build UI using data
            // ...

            return ListTile(
              title: Text(data['imei']),
              subtitle: Text(data['transactionType']),
              trailing: Text(
                data['trading'] != null
                    ? 'trading: ${data['trading']}'
                    : DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy')
                        .format(DateTime.parse(data['date'])),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> _showFilterDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Filter Options'),
          content: GetBuilder<FilteringController>(
            builder: (controller) => Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                _buildRadioButtons(),
                _buildDateRangePickers(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          actions: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Close the dialog
                setState(() {
                  // Update filters based on user selection
                });
              },
              child: Text('OK'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildRadioButtons() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text('Transaction Type:'),
        Row(
          children: [
            _buildRadioButton('In', 'In'),
            _buildRadioButton('Out', 'Out'),
            _buildRadioButton('', 'All'),
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10),
        Text('Trading Status:'),
        Row(
          children: [
            _buildTradingRadioButton(true, 'Trading'),
            _buildTradingRadioButton(false, 'Not Trading'),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildRadioButton(String value, String label) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Radio(
          value: value,
          groupValue: filteringController.selectedTransactionType,
          onChanged: (val) {
            filteringController.setSelectedTransactionType(val.toString());
          },
        ),
        Text(label),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTradingRadioButton(bool value, String label) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Radio(
          value: value,
          groupValue: filteringController.selectedTrading,
          onChanged: (val) {
            filteringController.setSelectedTrading(val);
          },
        ),
        Text(label),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildDateRangePickers() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text('Select Date Range:'),
        Row(
          children: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => _selectFromDate(context),
              child: Text(
                filteringController.selectedFromDate != null
                    ? DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy')
                        .format(filteringController.selectedFromDate!)
                    : 'From Date',
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 10),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => _selectToDate(context),
              child: Text(
                filteringController.selectedToDate != null
                    ? DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy')
                        .format(filteringController.selectedToDate!)
                    : 'To Date',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Future<void> _selectFromDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final selectedDate = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: filteringController.selectedFromDate ?? DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime(2020),
      lastDate: DateTime(2030),
    );
    if (selectedDate != null) {
      filteringController.setSelectedFromDate(selectedDate);
    }
  }

  Future<void> _selectToDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final selectedDate = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: filteringController.selectedToDate ?? DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime(2020),
      lastDate: DateTime(2030),
    );
    if (selectedDate != null) {
      filteringController.setSelectedToDate(selectedDate);
    }
  }
}
```

Getx controller:

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class FilteringController extends GetxController {
  String selectedTransactionType = '';
  bool? selectedTrading = null;

DateTime? selectedDateFilter; 
   DateTime? selectedFromDate;
  DateTime? selectedToDate;

  void setSelectedFromDate(DateTime? date) {
    selectedFromDate = date;
    update(); // Notify UI to rebuild
  }

  void setSelectedToDate(DateTime? date) {
    selectedToDate = date;
    update(); // Notify UI to rebuild
  }

  
  void setSelectedTransactionType(String value) {
    selectedTransactionType = value;
    update(); // This will rebuild the UI
  }
  void setSelectedTrading(bool? value) {
    selectedTrading = value;
    update(); // This will rebuild the UI
  }
  void setTodayDate(DateTime? value) {
    selectedDateFilter = value!;
    update(); // This will rebuild the UI
  }
  void setYesterdayDate(DateTime? value) {
   selectedDateFilter = value!;
    update(); // This will rebuild the UI
  }
  void setWeekAgoDate(DateTime? value) {
   selectedDateFilter = value!;
    update(); // This will rebuild the UI
  }
  void setMonthAgoDate(DateTime? value) {
    selectedDateFilter = value!;
    update(); // This will rebuild the UI
  }
}
```

Can anyone please help me identify what might be causing the issue? Am I missing something in my Firestore query or is there any specific consideration when filtering data by date range in Firestore queries?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You're ignoring errors in your `builder`. At the start of that code block add: `if (snapshot.hasError) { print(snapshot.error); return Text('ERROR: ${snapshot.error}'); }`

Comment: It isn't giving any error. When i choose dates for date filter it jsut says NO FILTERED DATA following code.
  var docs = snapshot.data!.docs;
        if (docs.isEmpty) {
          return Center(child: Text('No filtered data.'));
        }

But i have documnets in firesotre containing those dates.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the updated code, and its output.

Comment: Its updated code that i have posted in question, i am getting data with trading and transactionType filter but not getting by date filter. I dont even get any error.

Comment: If that's the latest code, you're still not handling the error in the way I described in my first comment.

Comment: Have updated now.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Do you know why i am not getting data by date filter? I am getting data by trading and transactionType filter but doesnt get by date filter.

Comment: Sorry, there is just too much going on in this code - so I recommend you [simplify it into a minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). My first guess now is that your string formats may be different between the database and the UI, but honestly: local debugging is your best way forward here. --- If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?